# Semigroup law on points on the curve $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$

Tags: group-theory, elliptic-curves, associativity

Consider the positive half of the curve $f: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}, f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$.  Let $A = (a,1/a), B = (b, 1/b)$ be any two points on the curve.  Draw a line through them  Find where this point intersects the curve $f$ reflected across the $y$-axis.  Now reflect the point back across the $y$-axis to yield the result that we define to be $A + B$.  This is diagrammed below.

[image]

It *appears* to be an associative operation:
[image]

However, proving it to be associative seems way more involved than just drawing lines.  What's an easy route to prove that curve point addition is associative?

My attempt: There is positive $y$ such that $A + (B-A)t = (-y, 1/y)$ iff $a + (b-a)t = -y$ and $1/a + (1/b - 1/a)t = 1/y$ which leads to the quadratic equation: $\left( \frac{a-b}{a} - a(\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a})\right )t + (\frac{1}{b} - \frac{1}{a})(a-b)t^2 -2 = 0$. This seems too complicated to work with on paper.

Comment: By drawing this in GeoGebra it seems to not be true.

Comment: Can it be the same way proved as for an elliptic curve using analogue of [Cayley–Bacharach theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley–Bacharach_theorem) for $x^2y^2-1=0$ ?

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin: As you have written it, that is not a cubic.

Comment: @Wojowu could you post a picture?

Comment: @EnjoysMath I have added an answer in which I provide a picture.

Comment: I have expanded my initial answer with a full proof, if you are still interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I hoped for a group law, I would begin by looking for the neutral element. In the case of elliptic curves, one works in projective coordinates and the neutral element is the point at infinity. In your case, the hyperbola is $xy=1$ so when you projectivize it you get $xy-z^2=0$. The trouble is that $z$ may now introduce a $-$ sign, which completely your idea (i.e. you cannot projectivize half of a hyperbola, you can only projectivize it all). So, the question would be: why work with only half a hyperbola?

**Edit:**

In order to find the coordinates of $(a,\frac 1 a) \oplus (b,\frac 1 b)$ it is conveninent to proceed as follows: intersect the line joining $A$ and $B$ (of equation $\frac {y-\frac 1 b} {x-b} = \frac {\frac 1 b - \frac 1 a} {b-a}$ or, equivalently, $y = \frac {a+b-x} {ab}$) with the hyperbola $xy=-1$; since you are looking for a negative solution, $x=\frac {a+b - \sqrt {(a+b)^2 + 4ab}} 2$. Then the $x$ coordinate of $A \oplus B$ will be the opposite of this, i.e. $x=\frac {\sqrt {(a+b)^2 + 4ab} \space -a -b} 2$.

Now, let us check whether $\big( (1,1) \oplus (1,1) \big) \oplus (2,\frac 1 2) = (1,1) \oplus \big( (1,1) \oplus (2,\frac 1 2) \big)$ (these points have been chosen to simplify computations). Rather than do it by hand, the following Mathematica code is faster:

`plus[{a_,_}, {b_,_}] := List[ (Sqrt [(a+b)^2+4 a b] - a - b) / 2, 2 / (Sqrt [(a+b)^2+4 a b] - a - b)];
(plus [plus [{1,1}, {1,1}], {2, 1/2}] - plus[{1,1}, plus[{1,1}, {2,1/2}]]) == {0,0}`

You will get "False", i.e. the two points do not coincide, so your operation is not associative.

**A final edit:**

There is, indeed, some deep similarity between conics and elliptic curves. You can find out more in [this paper by Franz Lemmermeyer](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0311306) that I have found delicious to read (mind you, from a certain point onwards he gets into higher mathematics).

Comment: OP wanted to make this into a semigroup, not a group.

Comment: @Wojowu: I do not know what the definition of a semigroup the OP uses; to me a semigroup must by definition contain a neutral element, and this is what I wanted to emphasize in my answer.

Comment: i missed the subtle humor first time round. (+1) for generating a good-natured, health-promoting laugh

Comment: I have consulted the definition from Wikipedia.

Answer (score 3):

Unless I have misunderstood OP, this seems not to be the case. I have drawn the following in GeoGebra, on which it is clearly false:

[image]

For clarity I didn't draw A+(B+C) nor (A+B)+C. These points would be reflections of A(BC) and (AB)C, respectively, in $y$ axis. From the picture it's clear that these will be distinct points.

Comment: Thanks.  Geogebra?  What a neat tool

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a proof. Plus, those points are so close that, to me, they almost prove the opposite.

Comment: @AlexM. For me, this is enough of a proof. If you really don't consider it to be enough, I'm not stopping you from working out a counterexample by hand.

Comment: @AlexM. In my opinion, no matter how I look, the two lines intersect at the point definitely not on hyperbola.

Answer (score 2):

modulo my unreliable arithmetic, the semi-group operation is:
$$
\theta_a \circ \theta_b = (\theta_a+\theta_b)\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{4\theta_a\theta_b}{(\theta_a+\theta_b)^2}} \right)}2
$$

which does not look too promising on the associativity front